# How to determine air intake holes in pc case

Tags: desktop-computer, case

My PC has a huge dust intake (I have two parrots and a cat occupying the room). So I don't want to unplug the pc and clean it from dust every week.
 I want to install exterior dust filters which I could clean without unplugging the PC.

I read somewhere that I should install the dust filters only on the air intake holes in my pc. How do I determine which are these?

This is my PC case - [BitFenix Merc Beta Gaming Case](http://www.bitfenix.com/global/en/products/chassis/merc-beta/)

Also I found out the dust builds up not only inside the computer but also clogs the 'holes', so is the advice concerning filters correct?

**Extra question:**

Is canned air safe to clean current dust? Sometimes I see bits of liquid when I spray it. 
It also says to always hold the can upright, but sometimes it's impossible to hold it upright to clean the place I need to clean.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical PC case is not designed for filtered air.  Apparently there was a conscience design decision to not require periodic filter maintenance,  That is, if the filters are not cleaned (which is likely for the lazy consumer) then the equipment will quickly overheat.
The typical PC case relies on negative case pressure (the fans blow air out) and circulates unfiltered air.  Overheating will not occur until dust accumulates over a longer period of time.

If you want a PC that is cooled with filtered air, then you have to convert your existing one (not really practical) or use a different case that utilizes positive air pressure.  Positive air pressure is maintained by blowing ***in*** filtered air, which will tend to keep dust out.  Trying to add filters to your existing case and plugging up every leak is not practical or likely to actually work as long as it uses negative case pressure.

> Also I found out the dust builds up not only inside the computer but also clogs the 'holes', so is the advice concerning filters correct?

That's the problem of using negative case pressure.  Every hole becomes an air intake, and would either have to be filtered or plugged up.

> Is canned air safe to clean current dust?

Yes.

> Sometimes I see bits of liquid when I spray it.

It should quickly evaporate, and leave no residue.  But if the equipment is still hot, then you could damage the it, most likely solder joints.  So only blast it when it's been powered off for a while (e.g. overnight).

But you should try to minimize this liquid condensation by holding the can properly, shake the can between blasts and avoid long blasts.

> It also says to always hold the can upright, but sometimes it's impossible to hold it upright to clean the place I need to clean.

Then you have to reposition the object that you're blasting, rather than tilt the can.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was most helpful. I still need to have a look at how to attain the positive air pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Generally fans suck the air inside and air leaves your case at the other holes. So intake holes are the ones where you have fan behind.
When you won't have dust inside the case then nothing will be able to build up around the holes.

Comment: It depends on fans air flow direction. Fan can be mounted so it will exhaust air.

Comment: The filter might restrict airflow, so you might need an auxiliary fan.

Comment: *"Generally fans suck the air inside and air leaves your case at the other holes"* -- You seem to be contradicting yourself.  Every PC PSU fan I've seen blows the air ***out*** of the case, not in.  When there's only one case fan, I've only seen them blow ***out*** of the case, not in.  The vents and holes are for air intake, not exhaust.